# Joomla template language

Tags: php, xml, joomla, localization, joomla-template

I have a custom Joomla template, to which I want to apply a template language file. I can put en_GB.tpl_my_tpl.ini into the appropriate place in the language folder of my website and everything works correctly. But I would like to put this files to my template folder so that to have easier access to my language files.

I read what people write about this and it seems to me that if I put template/my_template/language/en_GB/en_GB.tpl_my_tpl.ini it should work correctly but it does not. As far as I understand default Joomla templates use the same technique. I also add to my template xml the following but still no result.

```
<languages folder="language">
        <language tag=”en_GB”>en_GB.tpl_my_tpl.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Am I doing something wrong and how to overcome the matter?

Answer (score 0):

When `JLanguage::load()` is called the first parameter is the `$extension`, which in the case of templates is the template name e.g. `tpl_beez_20` (where `tpl_` is prepended to the template `name` during the ComponentHelper `renderComponent()` call in the `JSite`'s `dispatch()` method).

The `$template` name is retrieved via `$app->getTemplate(true)->template`, which originally comes from the template manifest `<name>beez_20</name>`.

So, as your small XML snippet looks OK, this could be a few things:

1. The `<name>` element doesn't have a value of `my_tpl` in it.
2. Your not actually re-installing the template just modifying the XML and for some reason Joomla isn't updating it's cached copy of the manifest — try using the `Discover` feature of the `Extension Manger`
3. Your template folder is not named correctly, in your question you have `/template/my_template` you may just have typed this incorrectly, but, if your `templateDetails.xml` is specifying `my_tpl` as the `<name>` your path should be `/templates/my_tpl/...` (While its been a few years since I've made a template the rule used to be that "the `name` tag must include the exact name of the folder that the template is to be installed under `/templates/`" See [TheArtOfJoomla](http://learn.theartofjoomla.com/building-templates/the-template-xml-file.html)

More details, like the key parts of the `templateDetails.xml` and a directory structure listing would also help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I understand what you mean, but the Discover function of extension manager gives no results concerning my template. As to the template names they are the same, I just typed incorrectly. As far as I see the only way is to reinstall the template?

Comment: Looks like it, at least that way the cached version will match your template package.

Comment: no, I updated my template with all necessary files and everything is in its place after I uninstall and newly install the updated template, but no way out, the string would not show any way, can't find out what could be the reason.

Comment: where is the string supposed to be showing front-end or back-end?

Answer (score 0):

We do the same exact thing for our custom templates. Everything looks good to include the folder name. Not sure why you were told that's wrong. Everything looks good except you're using "_" instead of "-". IE... you have:

```
<languages folder="language">
        <language tag="en_GB">en_GB.tpl_my_tpl.ini</language>
</languages>
```

This should be:

```
<languages folder="language">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.tpl_my_tpl.ini</language>
</languages>
```

If you ever run into any issue in regards to language translation problems, simply follow this debugging guide described in the official Joomla docs here:
http://docs.joomla.org/Making_templates_translatable#Debugging_a_translation